# How do I prioritize local hydrogen over remote hydrogen from a gas giant?

Tags: dyson-sphere-program

I recently exploited my local gas giant for hydrogen and fire ice, which is quite useful. The main reason was to get started on deuterium production for various advanced items. But I just noticed that my oil refining is falling far behind what my factory uses and I want to massively expand it now. But one by-product of oil refining is hydrogen and I'd like to avoid blocking the refined oil pathway if hydrogen accumulates.

The obvious solution would be to set this all up so that the hydrogen from the gas giant is only drawn upon last after all other local sources of hydrogen. But I don't really know how to set up my logistics stations for this, there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to set a priority here.

What options do I have to make sure that my gas giant hydrogen is used last, after using up all my locally produced hydrogen from oil refining and fire ice processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place two ILS. Set both to receive hydrogen, but uncheck "Orbital Collectors" in one of them. Add ships.

Now you can prioritize the non-orbital hydrogen by side-loading a belt or priority splitter.

Sideloading a belt is when you run one belt directly into another. The main belt will have priority. The side belt will add to the main belt when there's room.

You can also sideload with a belt-to-belt Sorter, but that's slower than a direct belt connection and requires power.

Splitters can be made into priority splitters by clicking on one that has more than one input and selecting which input should be the priority.

Answer (score 0):

Use bottlenecks to your advantage. I'm not sure how your logistics network is set up but if you want to use your local sources first, you need to just make sure the local source is in fact used first. If you transport the Gas Giant harvest to the same place your local pipes to, like a liquid storage tank for example... You can use a splitter with input priority on the local flow.

You could also just send all of the hydrogen byproduct into just thermal generators to get rid of it in a somewhat useful way.